# Connected Nested Lists in Jquery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Ey dudes, please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HG8k6/.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.containers").sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true
    });

    $("ul.containers").disableSelection();

    $("ul.rows").sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true
    });

    $("ul.rows").disableSelection();
});
```

It's working ok in some way, I have containers and rows, I can move them perfect, but what I really want to achieve is to move rows between containers, for example move the Row5 from Container2 to Container1. Thanks in advance and greetings from Colombia, South America!!

Answer (score 3):

Use  `connectWith:'.rows'` updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HG8k6/1/)

Comment: Great! It works! So I've advanced in this... but please take a look at the fiddle, my problem now is when I add a dynamic container with a row, the row can not be dragged... weird... If I just add a row, it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: just initialize sortable on newly added rows. I have updated fiddle please look http://jsfiddle.net/HG8k6/4/

Comment: Excellent! It's working great now, but why the container behavior is different from the row, both were added in a dynamic way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because jquery attaches sortable widget to parent and operates with it children, when u adding 'li.container' it is child of sortable 'ul.containers' and automatically li.container becaomes sortable but when you adding  ul.rows to newly added li.container you have to attach sortable to newly added ul.rows so it children becomes sortable.