# Connected Nested Lists in Angular with UI Sortable

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I would like to implement the following:

[Connected Nested Lists in Jquery UI Sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709838/connected-nested-lists-in-jquery-ui-sortable)

using Angular and the [Angular Jquery UI Sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable).  I need parents and children containers that are both sortable.  Parents that you can rearrange the order (within the set of parents) and children that you can rearrange and also drag to a different parent.

Is it possible with the Jquery UI Sortable Angular directive or do I have to create a new directive for having nested lists?

Here is a jsFiddle that was created to solve the previous question: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HG8k6/4/

```
$("ul.containers").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight-container",
    revert: true,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    axis: 'y',
    start: function (e, ui) {
        //alert("started");
    },
    update: function (e, ui) {
        //alert("updated");
        //save();
    }
});

function SetSortableRows(rows)
{
    rows.sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight-row",
    connectWith: "ul.rows:not(.containers)",
    containment: "ul.containers",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: true,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    axis: 'y',
    start: function (e, ui) {
        //alert("started");
    },
    update: function (e, ui) {
        //alert("updated");
        //save();
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

Take a look at angular-ui-tree: https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree.  It does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do two ui sortable, and connected them together.